# Invalid CSS Styles in Safari on Mac

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I developing on Next.js.

The problem is happening on the GridInput component that included two components.
At first, it styled correctly while I'm developing on Chrome until I open my website on Safari that notice me the problem.

I tried to check `<!doctype HTML>` and restart server already.

GridInput:

```
let error = '';
let data = '';

if (this.state.error.length) {
   error = (
      <div className={style.error_container}>
         <button className={style.error_btn} onClick={this.handleErrorClick}>X</button>
         <ul className={style.error_ul}>
            {this.state.error.map((err, i) => <li key={i} className={style.error_li}>{err}</li>)}
         </ul>
      </div>
   )
} else {
   error = ''
}

if (this.state.data?.length) {
   data = this.state.data.map(data => (
      <GridBody
         key={data}
         data={data}
         editable={this.props.isContentEditable}
         info={this.state.info.hasOwnProperty(data) ? this.state.info[data] : '-'}
         onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(undefined, data)}
         onEditClick={this.handleEditClick.bind(undefined, data)}
      />
   ))
} else {
   data = ''
}

<div className={style.settings + ' container'}>
   <button title="Clear data" className={style.reset_btn} onClick={this.handleResetClick}>X</button>
      <GridHeader
         title={this.props.title}
         subTitle={this.props.subTitle}
      />
   <form className={style.form} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} autoComplete="off">
      <input
         type="text"
         name="name"
         className={style.input}
         onKeyDown={this.handleInputKeyDown}
         onChange={this.onChange}
         value={this.state.name}
         disabled={this.state.type === 'edit' ? true : false}
         ref={this.inputRef}
      />
     <div className={style.input}>
         {
            this.props.isInfoRequired && <span className={style.optional} onClick={this.handleOptionalClick} ref={this.optionalRef}>(optional)</span>
         }
         <div contentEditable className={style.input_info} type="text" ref={this.infoRef} onFocus={this.handleInfoFocus} onBlur={this.handleInfoLostFocus} onKeyDown={this.handleInfoKeyDown} />
     </div>
     <input type="submit" className={style.input} />
   </form>
   {error}
   {data}
</div>
```

GridInput.module.css:

```
.settings {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;

    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.form {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70% 20% 10%;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 3rem;
    background: #1f1f23;
}

.input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #1f1f23;
    border-top: 3px solid #2b2c31fb;
    border-right: 3px solid #2b2c31fb;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.optional {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: rgb(177, 177, 177);
}
.input_info {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: #1f1f23;
    overflow: visible;
}
.input_info:focus {
    outline: none;
}
input.input:last-of-type {
    border-right: none;
}
.error_container {
    background: #1f1f23;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    /* margin-top: 10px; */
    border-top: 3px solid #2b2c31fb;
    position: relative;
}
.error_btn {
    background: transparent;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0.25rem;
    right: 0.25rem;

    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
}
.error_ul {
    margin: 0;
}
.error_li {
    margin: 0.25rem 0;
}
.reset_btn {
    color: #000;
    height: 2rem;
    width: 2rem;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5rem;
    right: 2.5rem;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```

GridHeader:

```
<header className={style.header}>
   <span className={style.head}>{props.title}</span>
   <span className={style.head}>{props.subTitle}</span>
   <span className={style.head}>-</span>
</header>
```

GridHeader.module.css:

```
.header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70% 20% 10%;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 3rem;
    background: #1f1f23;
}
.head {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 3px solid #2b2c31fb;
}
.head:last-of-type {
    border: none;
}
```

GridBody:

```
<div className={style.container} >
   <span className={style.body}>{props.data}</span>
   <span className={style.body}>{props.info}</span>
   <button className={style.body} onClick={props.onClick}>Delete</button>
   {props.editable ? <button className={style.edit} onClick={props.onEditClick}>Edit</button> : ''}
 </div>
```

GridBody.module.css:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70% 20% 10%;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 3rem;
    background: #1f1f23;
    position: relative;
}
.body {
    border-top: 3px solid #2b2c31fb;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 3px solid #2b2c31fb;

    font-size: 1rem;
    position: relative;
}
button.body {
    background: #1f1f23;
}
button.body:last-of-type {
    border-right: none;
}
.edit {
    width: 3rem;
    background: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -4rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);

    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

FireFox:
[Correct style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLmO4.png)

Chrome:
[Correct style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t00bF.png)

Safari:
[incorrect style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdtNm.png)

[My sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2zmwe?file=/pages/settings.js)

Comment: Please provide and share a sandbox to get help faster.

Comment: I have created [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2zmwe?file=/pages/settings.js)
But It's weird when I open the sandbox on safari it styled correctly.